# Accessing an EV3 brick on computer without MINDSTORMS Home

Tags: ev3, programming, compatibility

I am trying to hack my EV3, and I know I can make it execute commands I send via USB thanks to the [communication developer kit](https://education.lego.com/v3/assets/blt293eea581807678a/blt09ac3101d9df2051/5f88037a69efd81ab4debf2e/lego-mindstorms-ev3-communication-developer-kit.pdf).

When I connect it via USB, it is only visible by the MINSTORMS Home app and the `system report` (I am on Mac).

When I try to list serial ports, with for example `ls /dev/tty.*`, the EV3 doesn't show, which means I can't connect to it.

However, if their app does it, then there is a way around. Has anyone encountered this before, or does anyone know how their app does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bluetooth connection appears as a serial port, but USB does not. Instead USB on the EV3 appears as an HID device. So you will need a library that provides low-level (raw) access to HID devices.

Comment: I'll try that when I'll have the time, thanks for the answer !

Comment: For those who have the same problem and are looking for a library, go [here](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi)